# Github: How to add collaborator globally?

Tags: github, github-enterprise

I've got an account for automated builds which should have access to every Github (Enterprise) repository owned by a particular organization.  Is there a way to do this such that present and future repositories are automatically intercepted?

Comment: I suspect the answer is to [set up a team](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-teams/).

Comment: I took a look - unless I'm missing something, it appears that one has to add repositories one by one with teams as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the user as an owner:

1. Go to the 'People' tab under your organization.
2. Find the user of interest.  There are a number of columns, one of which has values such as 'member' or 'owner'.
3. Change this value for your user to 'owner'.

That user should now have contributor access to all repositories owned by the organization.